# How to find only 'permission granted' files

Tags: permissions, find

I'm trying to find files that I'm able to edit, I tried the commands below but still getting 'Permission denied' results.

```
find -name "*.config" | grep -v "Permission denied"

find -name "*.config" -perm /u+rw
```

And I still can see the results like:

```
find: `./proc/32609/task/32616/ns': Permission denied
```

Comment: get root at first with `sudo su` and enter your root password

Comment: you should remove tmpfs like /proc/ from your search. Those are not editable anyways.

Comment: You pipe the SYSOUT output from `find` to `grep`, but the SYSERR output passes un-`grep`-ed.

Comment: Many tasks in /proc are owned by root with no read write permissions to other users. Consider adding the option for filtering ownership. Cant recall off the tip of My head since I'm on cell phone.

Comment: Have you looked into `find`'s `-readable` and `-writable` options? They test permissions of the user that is the owner (more precisely the "effective user") of the `find` process. `-perm /u+rw` also finds files, that are owned by other users but on which the current user has no permissions.

Comment: * `-perm /u+rw` matches exactly those files, that are readable and writeable by their respective owner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One certainly could filter out the permission denied errors with `2> /dev/null` redirection, as it is an output from error stream.

```
find -name "*.config" -perm /u+rw 2> /dev/null
```

But also a good idea is to exclude those directories that give you problems with `-path /some/dir/*pattern -prune -o -print`.

```
 find /  -path "./proc*" -prune -o -name "*.config"  -print 2> /dev/null
```

It's also should be possible to exclude multiple directories with logical OR operator `-o` and grouping into `\( ... \)` brackets

```
find / -maxdepth 1 \( -not -path /etc* \) -o \( -not -path /var* \) -o \( -not -path /proc* \) -o \( -perm /u+rw -name "*.config" \)
```

Comment: @RinaldiSegecin always welcome :) Feel free to ask more questions on you the site. Let's learn together as a community !